# How can I hide enum constants from ReDoc?

Tags: openapi, redoc

I'm using OpenAPI v3 and springdoc and want to hide enum constants from ReDoc:

[image]
Note that I don't want to hide the attribute `status`. I want its constants to not appear in the API docs. How can I do such a thing?